# How to download search results of index page using axlsx?

Tags: ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-3.2, axlsx

First, I am really sorry if this question is too trivial. I am new with rails and couldn't figure out where i am doing it wrong.

I have a model named Costing and in it's index page i have a search form. I am trying to use 'axlsx' gem to **download only the search results** but I always get all the rows. I am also using 'will_paginate' gem.

Here is my code.

```
 //costings_controller.rb

def index
@costings = Costing.search(params[:search] , params[:page])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @costings }
  format.xlsx {
        send_data @costings.to_xlsx.to_stream.read, :filename => 'costings.xlsx', :type => "application/vnd.openxmlformates-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    }
end
end

// index.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Download Costings', url_for(:format=>"xlsx") %>
```

Please help me here.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/SriramK89/axlsx_demo) is the code that I made for a demo of axlsx gem. Browse through it and implement your requirement in the controller. [Here](http://axlsx-demo.herokuapp.com/) is the output of this demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
//costings_controller.rb

def download
@costings = Costing.search(params[:search] , params[:page])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @costings }
  format.xlsx {
        send_data @costings.to_xlsx.to_stream.read, :filename => 'costings.xlsx', :type => "application/vnd.openxmlformates-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    }
end
end

// index.html.erb
<%= form_for :costing, url: download_costing_index_path do %>
...
<% end %>

//routes
resources :costing do
    collection do
      post :download, :defaults => { :format => 'xlsx' }
    end
end
```

Comment: Rather than just posting code, try to add some comments about what is improved and why it works. Make your answers a teaching opportunity.